# VS 2008: Creating a web service from an existing wsdl file - Getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to convert an already created (in Eclipse) wsdl file, into a web service via VS 2008. 
I've found steps, to utilize the add WEB Reference on my web service existing project. It appears that my wsdl file is loaded into the web references, as I can see it in the solution explorer. Is there more I need to do once I complete the add web service function. Primarily to the service1.asmx.cs sheet. I published what I had, then uploaded to my Stage IIS server. I tried to access the service.asmx via an IE Browser on another jump server. **I get a runtime error: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely.** It then displays some web.config configuration file examples?

I then tried to access the link within the IIS server (local) environment. In the IE browser I get this message: The XML page can not be displayed. Can not view input using XSL style sheet. Please correct, then refresh. a name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource
**<%@ Webservice Language="C#"  CodeBehind="Service1.amsx.cs" Class="VSM2IDMService.service1" %> 
_^**

Thank you
Joe

Comment: IINM, the "web.config" sample (e.g. `customErrors=Off`) is saying "use this setting" so that the details are in fact displayed to you when you browse to the resource for debugging purposes (you can change it back later after you've debugged/fixed). Hth....